# Comma after "To this end"

Tags: conjunctions, commas

Does one put a comma after linking phrases such as *"To this end, we denote ..."*, *"For the purpose of the proof, we introduce an alternative notation ..."* etc. in formal (scientific, mathematical) writing?

I suppose the question is more complicated than a simple yes–no and there may be cases where the comma is expected and when it's unexpected, so I'm probably looking for some rule of thumb. I prefer British rules if that matters.

Comment: It's entirely a stylistic choice. You could get a feel for how often writers include a comma there by looking at some written instances of [to this end we](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to+this+end+we%22) and similar text strings in Google Books. But note that the trend over at least the past century has been to use ***less*** commas (in fact, less punctuation marks in general), so if you want to reflect *current* usage you should note that many older instances that include a comma probably *wouldn't* have done if they were written today.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is needed that you put a comma after it unless it has come at the end of the sentence. I don't see any difference between this and a phrase like "in my opinion", which a comma certainly comes after it.